# Elixir : verify IP present in particular range

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Need to check whether the given IP present in these multiple range or not

```
Given IP: 49.14.1.2
Ranges: 49.14.0.0 - 49.14.63.255, 106.76.96.0 - 106.76.127.255, and so on
```

I have tried by converting to integer and verifying the ranges. Is there any other way to do in IP itself without converting to integer

Comment: What are the original format of your IP address and IP ranges?

Comment: It will be in string format

Comment: Could you add here what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

If you know [CIDR IP notation](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr), then you can check to see if a particular IP Address is with in the IP range using:

```
> cidr = InetCidr.parse("49.14.0.0/16")
{{49, 14, 0, 0}, {49, 14, 255, 255}, 16}

> address = InetCidr.parse_address!("49.14.1.2") 
{49, 14, 1, 2}

> InetCidr.contains?(cidr, address)
true
```

https://github.com/Cobenian/inet_cidr

Answer (score 2):

Convert addresses into a tuple form using `:inet.parse_address/1` and compare using simple tuple comparison.

```
iex(33)> a_ip = :inet.parse_address(a)
{:ok, {49, 14, 1, 2}}
iex(34)> low_ip = :inet.parse_address(low)
{:ok, {49, 14, 0, 0}}
iex(35)> high_ip = :inet.parse_address(high)
{:ok, {49, 14, 63, 255}}
iex(36)> a_ip < low_ip
false
iex(37)> a_ip > low_ip
true
iex(38)> a_ip < high_ip
true
iex(39)> a_ip > high_ip
false
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any optimized way to check the given IP presence in each range, because there are almost 100 ip ranges

Comment: Beware that comparing string does not fit your need, for example `"25.12.14.10" < "25.12.5.10".` is true for string comparison, when it is obviously false for IP addresses comparison. So the tuple representation much better for your purpose, you can have a range representation as `{IpMin,IpMax}` where `IpMin` and `IpMax` are both a 4 elements tuple :`{XX,YY,ZZ,TT}`

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, I missed those cases. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @petspandaD If you use a tuple representation, checking should be cheap, as you only need to compare the ip address against two bounds for each range. If you want to further speed it up, you have to find a more suitable data structure, something similar to an index.

Comment: Thanks. Currently looking for optimized way for checking the IP range

`(Given_IP >= :inet.parse_address(low1) && Given_IP <= :inet.parse_address(high1)) || (Given_IP >= :inet.parse_address(low2) && Given_IP <= :inet.parse_address(high2)) || (Given_IP >= :inet.parse_address(low3) && Given_IP <= :inet.parse_address(high3))` and so on

Comment: You could write a tail recursive function to deal with it more elegantly

Comment: @petspandaD Regarding efficiency, do you need to find all matching ranges, or only the first matching range?

Comment: I have multiple carrier-Ip set, Need to find in which carrier-ip-set, given-ip  belongs to, I did like this,
`def ip_in_range(given_ip, [], carrier_id), do: nil 
def ip_in_range(given_ip, [{from_ip, to_ip} | rest], carrier_id) when ip >= from_ip and ip <= to_ip, do: carrier_id
def ip_in_range(given_ip, [{from_ip, to_ip} | rest], carrier_id) when ip < from_ip or ip > to_ip, do: ip_in_range(ip, rest, carrier_id)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tail recursive function to deal with the large list, and check each. Something along the lines of:

```
# First parameter: ip
# Second parameter the list of ranges in a tuple
# Third parameter the passed list, i.e. the ranges it does match
# It return the list of range(s) that the ip matched.
def ip_in_range(ip, [], match_list) do: match_list
def ip_in_range(ip, [{from_ip, to_ip} | rest], match_list) when ip > from_ip and ip < to_ip do: ip_in_range(ip, rest, [{from_ip, to_ip} | match_list])
def ip_in_range(ip, [{from_ip, to_ip} | rest], match_list) when ip < from_ip or ip > to_ip do: ip_in_range(ip, rest, match_list)
```

Then you could kick it off with the inet:parse_address/1 results, for example:

```
ranges = [{{49, 14, 0, 0}, {49, 14, 63, 255}}, ...]
ip_in_range({49, 14, 1, 2}, ranges, [])
```

You could mold this as much as you like, i.e. check how many ranges it belongs to. Or even exit on the first range check success.